# Sender and receiver pair in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying to understand the RabbitMQ server with a sender and a receiver program.  Now the entire setup works well when the sender sends a single message and the same would be received by the receiver.

however when i send two messages( by running sender twice) and run the receiver program twice i get only the first  message.

Sender

```
  ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();


        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
        String message = "He12!";
        channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());
        System.out.println("Sent "+message);
        channel.close();
        connection.close();
```

Receiver

```
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);

    QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
    channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, consumer);
    QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
    /*channel.basicCancel(consumer.getConsumerTag());   */

    String message;
     if (delivery != null) {
        message = new String(delivery.getBody());
        System.out.println("Reciever .."+message);

    }

    channel.close();
    connection.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was solved for me when i modified the Receiver with no_Ack = false and a call to  BasicAck. Thanks  to @robthewolf and @Card(by twitter) for helping .

PFB the modified receiver now.

```
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);

    QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
    channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, false, consumer);
    QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery(10);
    /*channel.basicCancel(consumer.getConsumerTag());   */

    String message = null;

     if (delivery != null) {
        message = new String(delivery.getBody());
        System.out.println("Reciever .."+message);
        channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);
    }

    channel.close();
    connection.close();
    return message;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it without the

```
channel.basicCancel(consumer.getConsumerTag());
```

line?

Additionally it would be much better to do something like this:

```
while(true){
  QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
  String message;
  if (delivery != null) {
    message = new String(delivery.getBody());
    System.out.println("Reciever .."+message);
  }
}
```

so that you have only one consumer consuming all messages in a loop.  This is just an example I just having a way to break out of the loop cleanly as opposed to having to ctrl-c.

Comment: Thanks for replying.. I had tried without the basicCancel(edited the code for the same)  but the problem remains the same. More over i thought will do it without a while loop so that the same can be exposed as a web service sending messages one at a time. Is it a bad idea to span a consumer per request ?

Comment: By executing the receiver in debug mode and running few commands in RabitMq server i observed that soon after the basicConsume function call is executed the queue size becomes zero ( command rabbitmqctl list_queues )

Comment: @praveena_kd what was the queue size before you execute the consumer?

Comment: @praveena_kd I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve by having a consumer only read and process one message.

Comment: I am planning to write this receiver code inside a servlet so that the web requests to that servlet can be responded with a single message at a time.
Queue size before executing the consumer was equal to number of message sent to that queue.